# .done after .animate callback function

Tags: jquery

I want call a function after .animate callback function. I am using .done method for this purpose but it is not working. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dWAP4/)

```
$(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
$('div').animate({width:'400px'},300,function(){alert(0)})
}).promise().done(function(){alert(1)})
})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were calling the `done` on the button element, not on the `div` which is animated

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').animate({
        width: '400px'
    }, 300, function () {
        alert(0)
    }).promise().done(function () {
        alert(1)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/F3pr6/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the promise on the `animate` function. At the minute, you have it on the `.click`:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('div').animate({width:'400px'},300,function(){alert(0)})
            .promise()
            .done(function(){alert("1")});
})
```