# jQuery flash an element onclick and after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have the following code:

```
$("#btn1").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#div").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    $("#div").addClass("flash");
    setTimeout( function(){
        $("#div").removeClass("flash"), 1000;
    }, 1000);
});
```

When I click on the button it will scroll down to the div and flash its color (`flash` class). But what if the div is at the bottom of the page? I need the ode above to be changed so that the `scrollTop` is executed first **AND is finished** and then execute the next piece of code (the `addClass` and the `setTimeout` function). I assume I need to add a delay? Or something that checks whether the function is complete and if so, start the next one?

Comment: Here's a couple questions that might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547888/jquery-animate-and-done

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359763/done-after-animate-callback-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is animation callback. It's the forth parameter to the `.animate()` method: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

So in your case it would look like this:

```
$("#btn1").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#div").offset().top
    }, 
    2000, 
    'swing', 
    function () {
        $("#div").addClass("flash");
        setTimeout( function(){
            $("#div").removeClass("flash"), 1000;
        }, 1000);
    });

});
```

Btw. **it's a good practice to cache a jQuery selectors** for optimisation (jQuery won't be searching the DOM for the queried nodes, and running the its constructor function each time).

I also refactored this code a bit for readability and to separate the flashing functionality, so you can either use it conveniently in such callbacks (in which case the function will get the animated element as `this` object, or just run it directly, passing it any jQuery element (e.g. `flash($('.anything'))`)

```
$("#btn1").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $div = $('#div');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $div.offset().top
    }, 2000, 'swing', flashElement});
});

function flashElement(element) {
    element = element || this;
    element.addClass("flash");
    setTimeout( function(){
        element.removeClass("flash"), 1000;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a callback...

```
$("#btn1").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#div").offset().top
    }, 2000, function(){
     $("#div").addClass("flash");
        setTimeout( function(){
            $("#div").removeClass("flash"), 1000;
        }, 1000);  
    });
});
```